Why is lambda calculus favoured for formal verification?
Theorem provers like Coq, Agda, etc use lambda calculus as a foundation, right?
Why is lambda calculus favoured over other models computation?
Is it that in the case of Turing machine there are problems like (not sure if these are accurate):

composition is difficult
statefulness or lack of immutability

If these are some of the problems, why are other models of computation not favoured?
(I am not familiar with any other models beyond their names though.)
Then again, there are tools like iris.
Is iris based on a form of lambda calculus as well?
I suppose it is, since it sits atop Coq?

I saw a possibly related reddit post.

λ-calculus fits naturally in the computational trilogy.

There are many variants of $\lambda$-calculus. Proof assistants like Coq, Agda and Lean do not use the the pure $\lambda$-calculus but rather dependent type theory, which is an extension of the (simply typed) $\lambda$-calculus.
The reason for this is the Curry-Howard correspondence which allows us to handle with a single formalism, namely dependent type theory, logic, math, and computation. For example, we can use types to:

define mathematical structures, such as groups, rings, real numbers, metric spaces, etc.
organize such structures in abstract herarchies,
express logical statements and prove them by constructing suitable terms
implement data structures, such as lists, trees, streams, etc.
implement algorithms with proofs that they are correct.

The formalism of Turing machines is not meant to capture any of the above. Rather, it was invented to give a satisfactory account of what computation is in the first place. In contrast, Martin-Löf's type theory was designed to capture the constructive (and therefore compuational) aspects of foundations of mathematics.

To complement Andrej's answer, beyond the Curry-Howard correspondence there is also another important aspect: binding.
One area where λ-calculus shines (and which, as far as I understand, it was originally conceived for), is to give good primitives to work with bound variables and substitution thereof. Binding and substitutions are the core concept from which computation arises in the λ-calculus.
Bound variables and substitution are everywhere in logic, from quantifiers to explicit function definitions. This, maybe even more elementarily than the CH correspondence, makes λ-calculus and logic fit nicely together.
